# PyDev Branch Coverage

Tags: python, pydev, coverage.py

Is there any way to configure PyDev's coverage.py integration to spit out a report with branch coverage?

I see in the resulting command line in the run configuration, that `Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.4.0.201510052309/pysrc/pydev_coverage.py .metadata/.plugins/org.python.pydev.debug/coverage/.coverage.2
run --source` is being run, there is just a `--branch` missing. But I found no way to insert it at this position as you can only give arguments to the interpreter or the main module, but not the coverage runner in the run configuration.

**Edit**

A [.coveragerc](http://coverage.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html) configuration file at the working directory works partially, the output in Eclipse is then messed up and missed lines highlighting is broken:

```
Name                                      Stmts     Miss      Cover  Missing
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
__init__.py                                   2        -       100%  0   100%
rest/__init__.py                              2        -       100%  0   100%
rest/django/attribute.py                     12        -       100%  0   100%
rest/django/operation.py                    114        5      95.6%  0    96%   24-28
rest/django/view.py                          16       16         0%  2     0%   1-39
rest/django/serialization.py                  4        -       100%  0   100%
rest/django/request.py                       15       15         0%  0     0%   1-21
rest/django/__init__.py                       2        -       100%  0   100%
rest/django/resource.py                      24       24         0%  0     0%   1-38
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                       191       60      68.6%
```

Comment: A .coveragerc file is the way to do it.  I've never seen output that looks like that, where did it come from?

Comment: This is how it is rendered in the [PyDev Coverage View](http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_coverage.html). When I run coverage in the console, the output looks fine and includes the branch headers. Seems like PyDev did not expect or does not support branch coverage. My hope was, that PyDev would maybe support a hidden option to help branch coverage results integrate better in the IDE.

Comment: I'd ask the PyDev people. it sure looks like they are mis-rendering it.